# Find a **bijection** between two intervals

Tags: infinity

I am struggling with this question and was hoping somebody could help me, Thanks

Find a bijection between the intervals $(-1,1)$ and $(0,4)$ where $X \in R$

Comment: What is $X$? And what did you try? And why the "infinity" tag?

Comment: You can consider the equation of a straight line.

Comment: Are you shure about $(1,1)$?

Comment: Do you mean first interval $(0,1)$? Because $(1,1)$ is empty.

Comment: Once the intervals are corrected, try maps of the form $x\mapsto ax+b$

Comment: Sorry it is between the interval (-1,1) and (0,4). I didn't know how to get the bijective so I tried getting the injective and the surjective but that confussed me even more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f:(\color\red{-1},\color\green{1})\rightarrow(\color\orange{0},\color\purple{4})$

$f(x)=(x-(\color\red{-1}))\cdot\frac{\color\purple{4}-\color\orange{0}}{\color\green{1}-(\color\red{-1})}+\color\orange{0}=2x+2$

---

$g:(\color\orange{0},\color\purple{4})\rightarrow(\color\red{-1},\color\green{1})$

$g(x)=(x-\color\orange{0})\cdot\frac{\color\green{1}-(\color\red{-1})}{\color\purple{4}-\color\orange{0}}+(\color\red{-1})=\frac12x-1$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is that a formula that you used to get the answer? Sorry, just wondering for in future if i get a similar question again. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Emma: Yes, I've used four different colors in order to make it clear what the formula is.

Answer (score 0):

the bijection between two open intervals is simple the line joining those two points where "y" is f(x)

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear what you mean...